# Check the ThreadStackSize programmatically?

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss7.x, java.util.concurrent

Is there a way to check the ThreadStackSize programmatically?

I have the following code in  Jboss 7's jboss.conf file.

```
 # Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=false
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dlogging.configuration=file:%JBOSS_HOME%/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
wrapper.java.additional.9=-Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl

**wrapper.java.additional.10=-XX:ThreadStackSize=256k**
```

Is there a way to confirm if the ThreadStackSize has been set to 256k programmatically?

Comment: I dont think you should be putting the 'k' in the argument for ThreadStackSize.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the -XX args are implementation specific, so the core Java classes can't expose that information directly as a simple `getMaxStackSize()`.

There are a lot of useful metrics in the `java.lang.management` package, such as the [`MemoryPoolMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html). I haven't tried looking for stack size in particular, but if you dig around you might find it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read here: [Update a java thread's stack size at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136281/update-a-java-threads-stack-size-at-runtime)

You could probably try to grab the [`stackSize`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Thread.java#195) variable using reflection and see if that gives you anything useful. Be wary:

```
/*
 * The requested stack size for this thread, or 0 if the creator did
 * not specify a stack size.  It is up to the VM to do whatever it
 * likes with this number; some VMs will ignore it.
 */
```