# How can I change the stack size (of a thread) in my Android Application?

Tags: java, android, timertask, stack-size

I'm getting a stackoverflow error in my service which is attached my to my main activity. Is there a way to change the stack size within my service ? I came across  the Xss parameter, however, apparently its not available in the vm options (Help->Edit vmoptions).

**A bit of the background:**
I'm getting the error when I try to read a serialized machine learning model in code and then de-serialize it. The same function works fine when this model is built on a small dataset, but doesn't work when I built the same model with a bigger daatset.

Any ideas on how can I do it ?

Comment: i think you need to optimize your code before asking that

Comment: @zombie I'm deserializing " Neural Network Classifier" which is built a big dataset so I don't think that it has to do anything with my code optimization.

Comment: did you try  android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html

Comment: @Zombie that for heap size. However, I'm referring to stack size, not heap size.

Comment: Not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10136476/926907 You will have to rewrite your serializer in non-recursive way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the stack size of your app, however you can create a new thread and set the stack size for new thread using this constructor:

constructor [Thread (ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String,%20long))

Anyway a new thread is a good idea as you get a clean stack. The Android main thread has already about 10 entries that belong to Dalvik and other parts of the system...

Comment: I don't want to change the stack size of the whole app but only the timer thread which I am using. I'm TIMER TASK and timer for a periodic task in my app.

Comment: You can't change the thread used by `Timer`. Hence you need a second thread with adapted stack size you can trigger from your `TimerTask`.