# Depth First Search recursive calls cause StackOverflow error

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, depth-first-search, maze

I mam using an implementation of the Depth First Search Algorithm in order to solve a maze. I do not wish for the shortest path to be found but for the fastest way to find a valid path. This is the method i use to solve mazes. Mazes are 2d int arrays where 0 is an open square, 1 is a wall, 2 is a visited square and 9 is the destination.

```
    public class DepthAlgorithm {

/**
 * This method returns true when a path is found. It will also fill up the
 * list with the path used. It will start from (xn,yn,.....,x2,y2,x1,y2)
 * because it will use recursion.
 * @param maze 2d array of maze
 * @param x the x of the starting position
 * @param y the y of the starting position
 * @param path a List of the path
 * @return True if a path is found
 */
public static boolean searchPath(int [][] maze, int x, int y, List<Integer> path){
    // Check if the destination (9) is reached
    if (maze[y][x] == 9) {
        path.add(x);
        path.add(y);
        return true;
    }

    // When the current position is not visited (0) we shall make it visited (2)
    if (maze[y][x] == 0) {
        maze[y][x] = 2;

        //Here we visit all neighbour squares recursively and if a path is found
        // we shall fill the path list with the current position.
        int dx = -1;                // Start and search from starting
        int dy = 0;                 // position (x-1,y)
        if (searchPath(maze, x + dx, y + dy, path)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }

        dx = 1;                    // Start and search from starting
        dy = 0;                    // position (x+1,y)
        if (searchPath(maze, x + dx, y + dy, path)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }

        dx = 0;                   // Start and search from starting
        dy = -1;                  // position (x,y-1)
        if (searchPath(maze, x + dx, y + dy, path)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }

        dx = 0;                   // Start and search from starting
        dy = 1;                   // position (x,y+1)
        if (searchPath(maze, x + dx, y + dy, path)) {
            path.add(x);
            path.add(y);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

My algorithm works fine for small maze sizes. When i want to solve a 50 * 50 maze it's quite quick. When i move to 500 * 500 a Stack Overflow error shows up. I can understand that it shows up because of the many recursive calls of the function but i do not know how to fix it. **Is there another way so I can still use the Depth First Search and store my path but without the Stack Overflow? Or are there any changes that can be done in my code so it can be fixed?**

```
public class MazeRunner {

// Maze is a 2d array and it has to be filled with walls peripherally
// with walls so this algorithm can work. Our starting position in this
// will be (1,1) and our destination will be flagged with a 9 which in
// this occasion is (11,8).
private int[][] maze ;
private final List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
public long startTime,stopTime;

public MazeRunner(int [][] maze){
    this.maze = maze;
}

public void runDFSAlgorithm(int startingX,int startingY){
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    DepthAlgorithm.searchPath(maze,startingX,startingY,path);
    stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    printPath();
    System.out.println("Time for Depth First Algorithm: "+((double) (stopTime-startTime) / 1_000_000)+" milliseconds");

}

public void printPath(){
    ListIterator li = path.listIterator(path.size());
    int lengthOfPath = (path.size()/2-1);
    int fromX,fromY,bool = 0,toX = 0,toY = 0,i = 2;
    while(li.hasPrevious()){
        if (bool == 0) {
            fromX = (int) li.previous();
            fromY = (int) li.previous();
            toX = (int) li.previous();
            toY = (int) li.previous();
            System.out.println("From ("+fromY+", "+fromX+") to ("+toY+", "+toX+")");
            bool++;
            continue;
        }
        if (bool == 1){
            fromX = toX;
            fromY = toY;
            toX = (int) li.previous();
            toY = (int) li.previous();
            System.out.println("From ("+fromY+", "+fromX+") to ("+toY+", "+toX+")");
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nLength of path is : "+lengthOfPath);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int [][] maze = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                     {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                     {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
                     {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                     {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1},
                     {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
                     {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1},
                     {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
                     {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,9,1},
                     {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};
   MazeRunner p = new MazeRunner(maze);
   p.runDFSAlgorithm(startingPoint[0],startingPoint[1]);
}
```

}

And this is the class i use for my testings. It for sure works for this example but for greater arrays it doesn't. **Any suggestions would be appreciated**. When i run my program on big arrays i get this following error:

[image: error messages]

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking there are only two possibilities that could cause a stackoverflow exception
1.memory of stack is not enough
2.there exist a dead loop which in using recursive means it does't exist an end condition.

Since you algo works for small size maze. It’s possible the reason one. As you know the rule of recursive is first in last out, in JVM all the data of unexecuted functions will be stored in stack which owns a much smaller memory than heap.

Comment: So what's a solution?

Comment: Debug your code and find out where an infinite loop starts.

Comment: There is no infinite loop in my code. The problem is caused of recursion.

Comment: Okay, your recursion does not end where it should be. Probably, some condition should be checked in the beginning of  recursive function's body. Briefly checked your code. How will it work if it's not possible to reach target point? How will i then exit the recursion?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, the program is working correctly for small mazes(50*50). But for big arrays as I can understand the function is being called too many times and the stack doesn't have any more memory. That's the reason i think and i do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Actually every thread of java has his own stack, you can configure the default memory size distributed by using java commode in console. But i never tried, if you really want to give it a shot you can see this response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136281/update-a-java-threads-stack-size-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

You should never use a recursive algorithm for real work unless you know for certain that the depth of the stack will be limited to a reasonable number.  Usually that means O(log N), or O(log^2 N) at most.

DFS for a 500x500 maze could put around 250000 function calls on the stack, which is way too many.

You can use DFS if you really want to, but you should maintain your own stack in a separate data structure.  BFS would be better though, unless there's some reason you really don't want the shortest path.

Comment: Subscribing to this answer. Recursive solutions are fancy, beautiful and smart.. when you solve some homework or interview challenge task asks you for it; however, it really gets a heavy load as soon as stack increases.. which, often times, happen quite fast.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thank you very much for your answer. I actually need to find a solution to the maze which in not the shortest one (If there are more than 1 paths). I really like the way this method works and i would like to use it if there's a possible way. Is there any certain thing you would recommend me to do so i get this working for such big arrays? Thanks.